# Bugzilla - Internal Server Error 500

Tags: apache, cgi, wamp, httpd.conf, bugzilla

I am working on Windows 7 with **WAMP** server and I want to install **Bugzilla** on my desktop. After the installation, when I first tried to log into Bugzilla, the index.cgi was not interpreted but displayed as text. So I updated the httpd.conf file by adding the following code:

```
<Directory "C:/wamp/www/bugzilla-5.0.1">
   Options +ExecCGI
   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

But now I have the following error:
**Internal Server Error**

I tried to remove the **.htaccess** and updated httpd.conf in many ways but I still have this issue. Does anybody know how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In apache log file you can view the exact error thrown by Bugzilla, which will provide lead to fix the issue or share with us to help you